# Nodejs, koa-router, koa-views (twig) return "Not found"

Tags: node.js, koa2, koa-router

So I started my new project and a friend of mine conveiced me to ditch PHP and give Nodejs a try with rethinkDB.

I installed everything and without routes, it works. But once I add the routes, I got : `Not Found` with no error on the console.

**Packages**:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "keygrip": "^1.0.1",
    "koa": "^2.3.0",
    "koa-controller": "^1.1.0", //Not used - discontinued ?
    "koa-response-time": "^2.0.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.2.1",
    "koa-views": "^6.0.2",
    "rethinkdbdash": "^2.3.29",
    "socketio": "^1.0.0",
    "twig": "^1.10.5"
  }
```

**server.js**:

```
var Koa = require('koa'),
      Router = require('koa-router'),
      keygrip = require("keygrip"),
      r = require('rethinkdbdash')(),
      views = require('koa-views'),
      Twig = require('twig'),
      twig = Twig.twig,
      app = new Koa(), // Init Koa
      router = new Router(); //Init router

//configure VIEWS
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views/', { extension: 'twig', map: {twig: 'twig' }}))

//Initialize controllers
var ot = require(__dirname+'/controllers/ot.js');

//app.keys = ['im a newer secret', 'i like turtle'];

router
  .get('/', async function (ctx, next) {

      async (ctx, next) => {
        /*ctx.state = {
          session: this.session,
          title: 'app'
        };*/
        ctx.render('index', {
            message: 'Hello world! <3'
        });
      };
  });

app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
console.log('server listen on http://localhost:3000');
```

**ot.js**:

```
var ot = function() {};

ot.prototype = {
    'index' : async function(ctx, next) {

        ctx.state = {
            session: this.session,
            title: 'app'
        };

        await ctx.render('index', {
            message: 'Hello world! <3'
        });

        console.log(ctx);

    }
};

module.exports = new ot();
```

My goal would be to achieve something like:

```
router.get('/', master.index);
router.post('/search', master.search);
router.get('/ot', ot.index);
router.get('/ot/:id', ot.getById);
```

Total nodejs noob, I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this should work: for the **index.js** change it to:

```
'use strict';

const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const keygrip = require("keygrip");
// const r = require('rethinkdbdash')(); // not needed in this code at the moment
const views = require('koa-views');
const Twig = require('twig');
const twig = Twig.twig;

const app = new Koa(); // Init Koa
const router = new Router(); //Init router

//configure VIEWS
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views/', { extension: 'twig', map: {twig: 'twig' }}))

//Initialize controllers
var ot = require(__dirname+'/controllers/ot.js');

app.keys = ['im a newer secret', 'i like turtle']; // not needed in this code at the moment

router
  .get('/', async function (ctx, next) {
      await ctx.render('index', {
          message: 'Hello world! <3'
      });
  });

// routes from ot.js
router.get('/ot', ot.index);

app
    .use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
console.log('server listen on http://localhost:3000');
```

and your **controllers/ot.js** could then look like this:

```
'use strict';

exports.index = async function (ctx, next) {
    await ctx.render('index', {
        message: 'Hello - FROM ot/index'
    });
};

exports.someOther = async function (ctx, next) {
    // some other function
};
```

My sample **views/index.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        {{ message }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Both routes `localhost:3000/` and `localhost:3000/ot` should work now. The RethinkDB part is missing here because you did not provided any sample code. Hope that helps.